# Deadlock Issues on SQL Server, Update update

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, deadlock, database-deadlocks

First of all, I hate deadlocks as I can never work out why, I got this deadlock on our database and I can't seemed to work out how to fix it, basically it says it's a key lock.

Environment:
Azure Hyper-Scale 2-Vcore

we have 2 merge statements that run at the same time and seem to cause the deadlock.

Merge statement 1:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; 
MERGE [Q_Net_Ml_PlayerLifecycleDuration] t USING @Data s ON t.MerchantID = s.MerchantID and t.ExternalCustomerID = s.ExternalCustomerID 
WHEN MATCHED THEN

    UPDATE SET TimeID = s.TimeID, StageID = s.StageID, Duration = s.Duration, PredictionStageID = s.PredictionStageID, PredictionDuration = s.PredictionDuration, DaysSinceSignin = s.DaysSinceSignin, DaysSinceDeposit = s.DaysSinceDeposit, DaysSinceWager = s.DaysSinceWager, DaysSincePayout = s.DaysSincePayout, DaysSinceBonus = s.DaysSinceBonus, DaysSinceWithdrawal = s.DaysSinceWithdrawal, DateCreated = GETUTCDATE()

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN

    insert (MerchantID, ExternalCustomerID, TimeID, StageID, Duration, PredictionStageID, PredictionDuration, DaysSinceSignin, DaysSinceDeposit, DaysSinceWager, DaysSincePayout, DaysSinceBonus, DaysSinceWithdrawal, DateCreated)
    values (s.MerchantID, s.ExternalCustomerID, s.TimeID, s.StageID, s.Duration, s.PredictionStageID, s.PredictionDuration, s.DaysSinceSignin, s.DaysSinceDeposit , s.DaysSinceWager, s.DaysSincePayout, s.DaysSinceBonus, s.DaysSinceWithdrawal, GETUTCDATE())
OPTION (MAXDOP 1,IGNORE_NONCLUSTERED_COLUMNSTORE_INDEX);
```

Merge Statement 2:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.Q_Net_Ml_PlayerLifecycleDuration AS ExistingEvent  
USING (SELECT MerchantID, ExternalCustomerID, StageID, TimeID, ActivityTimeID  
 FROM OPENJSON(@Events)  
 WITH ([MerchantID] int, [TimeID] int, [ExternalCustomerID] varchar(50), [StageID] int, [ActivityTimeID] int)) AS NewEvent  
 ON (ExistingEvent.MerchantID = NewEvent.MerchantID  
 AND ExistingEvent.ExternalCustomerID = NewEvent.ExternalCustomerID)  
WHEN MATCHED THEN  
  
 UPDATE SET  
 StageID = NewEvent.StageID,  
 DateCreated = @Now,  
 Duration = @TimeIDNow - NewEvent.ActivityTimeID,  
 TimeID = NewEvent.TimeID,  
 PredictionStageID = 0,  
 PredictionDuration = 0  
  
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
  
 INSERT (TimeID, ExternalCustomerID, MerchantID, StageID, DateCreated, Duration, PredictionStageID, PredictionDuration)  
 VALUES(NewEvent.TimeID,  
  NewEvent.ExternalCustomerID,  
  NewEvent.MerchantID,  
  NewEvent.StageID,  
  @Now,  
  @TimeIDNow - NewEvent.ActivityTimeID,  
  0,  
  0)OPTION (MAXDOP 1,IGNORE_NONCLUSTERED_COLUMNSTORE_INDEX);
```

Q_Net_Ml_PlayerLifecycleDuration is partitioned on MID

when it runs it seems to have following deadlock issue:

This seems like an update issue as using mode = U
but I can't seem to find on google anything with mode = U on both

I have tried some hints but mainly just guessing to see if would help sometimes causes more issues.

Table details:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Q_Net_Ml_PlayerLifecycleDuration](
    [RecordID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MerchantID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ExternalCustomerID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TimeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StageID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Duration] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PredictionStageID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PredictionDuration] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DaysSinceSignin] [int] NULL,
    [DaysSinceDeposit] [int] NULL,
    [DaysSinceWager] [int] NULL,
    [DaysSincePayout] [int] NULL,
    [DaysSinceBonus] [int] NULL,
    [DaysSinceWithdrawal] [int] NULL
)
```

size of table:
2045675 rows 981664 KB Data 1402832 KB  Index sizes

Partitioned by MerchantID e.g. 1, 2, 3, 17, 100,200,250 etc..
Indexes on the table:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [CI_Q_Net_Ml_PlayerLifecycleDuration] ON [dbo].[Q_Net_Ml_PlayerLifecycleDuration]
(
    [ExternalCustomerID] ASC,
    [MerchantID] ASC,
    [StageID] ASC
)
```

lock_escalation:
Auto

Then a Non-clustered columnstore index for the rest of the fields but disabled in the merge statement.

also I noticed there are other scripts that run against this table and noticed lck_M_IX and LCK_M_U

Blitz table report shows me:
Row lock waits: 51; total duration: 4 minutes; avg duration: 5 seconds; Page lock waits: 503; total duration: 24 seconds; avg duration: 0 seconds; Lock escalation attempts: 32,797; Actual Escalations: 543;

Comment: `MERGE` [isn't as atomic as you may think](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/). It's actually multiple operations and the changes *are* visible to other transactions. The two statements may easily be trying to modify rows created by each other, or at least, taking Shared locks that prevent updates. You need to add a `HOLDLOCK` to the target at least. Perhaps it would be better to use separate `UPDATE` and `INSERT` statements in a transaction instead.

Comment: Besides, no matter how the target is indexed, the JSON data is *not* indexed and the query optimizer has no idea what's in there and may not pick a good execution plan. It would be better to store the data in a permanent, indexed staging table and update the target. If you have frequent updates, an in-memory table would reduce contention

Comment: Finally, the operations modify the clustered index itself. They're actually rearranging rows on disk. As for partitioning, precisely because the server has no idea what's in `@data` or `@Events`, it may decide to touch *all* partitions. Even with a staging table though, the index won't align with the partitions

Comment: You should explain the *original* problem. It looks like the attempts to "improve" performance caused even worse problems. Partitions are a data management feature, not a performance feature. And definitely not a multi-tenancy feature. Partitions make moving partitions between tables easier. They don't improve disk IO.

Comment: Please share execution plans for both queries via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: @Charlieface there are several serious problems in the question. I doubt the execution plan would help at this point. The *clustered* index includes the column that's modified. That means that each INSERT or UPDATE has to move rows around. The partition is made on the *middle* field of the clustered index. At the very least, this means that the server has to scan all partitions. Finally, the input data isn't indexed.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The partition being on the middle field I don't see why that's relevant. `StageId` being modified is perhaps an issue, although it's most likely that will manifest as a Split/Collapse and end up on the same page anyway (because it is the last key column). The input data not being indexed can also perhaps be solved by forcing a sort. But we can't know what the actual issue is until we see the plans

Comment: Sorry please also add the deadlock graph xdl to the question

Comment: @Charlieface  i think this is the one: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy3bqlHo_  and deadlock plan: https://pastebin.pl/view/b5cc4d1f

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJBrzWSi_ another one i found

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos many thanks for help basically we put partitions on the table as we were told it should help e.g. if we are were to update mid 10 then it should only update rows in that partition, so we basically only merge on mids, so it should process mid 10 once all done move to next mid 11 and so on, but I  think it runs on mid 10 and the process takes longer then another process comes and starts updating mid 10 then it causes deadlock, but it could also be mid 11 tbh I am not sure a lot goes on during the issues lots of locking going on. still learning. I added maxdop as read it helped

Comment: It looks like the issue might be because the queries pull existing data from `Q_Net_Ml_PlayerLifecycleDuration` out of order, and then sort them afterwards. This is because there is no uniqueness guarantee over the join columns. You could try solving this by changing `@Data` in merge1 to have a *unique* key or clustered index over `ExternalCustomerID, MerchantID`. And in merge2 change the `OPENJSON` subquery to group by those two columns and take `MIN` or `MAX` of all other columns.